# SqlConnection - Veracode scan cwe-15: external control of system or configuration issue

Tags: c#, azure-functions, sqlconnection, veracode

In an Azure function, I am creating a SQL connection by accessing an Azure function configuration setting `mydbconstring` which is a keyvault reference setting. So this `mydbconstring` is secured information since it is stored in keyvault. I am using below code to create the `SqlConnection` in the Azure function.

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("mydbconstring", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process)))
{
    // code here
}
```

In the Veracode scan we get below high severity issue `cwe-15: external control of system or configuration`  for the above line.
But how this actually a issue when I have the connection string as a keyvault reference configuration in function app which I think is secured. Is there any need for mitigation here or is it a false positive. If mitigation is required - then what should be the approach for the fix?

Comment: It's not an issue, under certain conditions. The tool doesn't know the code is running in a container. If the code was running on a normal server or VM, an attacker that gained shell access to it could read all environment variables and hence read the password. This isn't an idle threat or a "well if they get shell access you've lost already". Older web app frameworks, especially in Perl or PHP, would execute shell commands for various jobs. Or they'd generate dynamic scripts using user input. You could actually generate and run a script that would return all environment variables this way

Comment: So, if your container (and Functions run in containers) only allows your application to run, if the application itself doesn't try to do "clever" things like dynamic scripting, then no, this isn't a threat.

Comment: PS: `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` doesn't read anything from Key Vault, it' reads an environment variable that was set by the Azure platform, using credentials received from Key vault. That's common with Kubernetes and container orchestration in general. It's secure because the application code doesn't even need to access Key Vault and nothing else is allowed to run inside the container.